# Shell script to split a url and extract the variables

Tags: bash, sh

I have a string like this "git@github.com:myOrg/my-repo.git", I am trying to split the url string and get the substrings "myOrg" and "my-repo".

I tried below script but it is failing

```
REPO=$(echo $SSH_URL | sed  -n 's#.*:\\(.*\\)/.*#\\1#p')

GIT_ORG=$(echo $SSH_URL | sed -n 's/^.*:\\([^\\/]*\\)\\/\\(.*\\)\\.git$/\\1/p')
```

but I am getting below error

`sed: -e expression #1, char 39: unknown option to s`

can someone please help

Comment: As the [tag:bash] tag you used says "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here." and also please read [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization). Once you've fixed your code based on that, if you still have problems [edit] your question to show the updated code and let us know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to cut off the unneeded parts:

```bash
url="${SSH_URL}"   # make a copy
url="${url#*:}"    # drop until colon
url="${url%.git}"  # drop extension

owner="${url%/*}"  # extract "myOrg"
repo="${url#*/}"   # extract "my-repo"
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `read` builtin: (**edit:** added the stripping of `.git` with a parameter expansion)

```bash
#!/bin/bash

SSH_URL=git@github.com:myOrg/my-repo.git

IFS=':/' read -r _ git_org git_repo <<< "${SSH_URL%.git}"
```

```bash
$ echo "$git_org"
myOrg
$ echo "$git_repo"
my-repo
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a regular expression.

```
[[ $SSH_URL =~ git@github.com:(.*)/(.*)\.git ]]
REPO=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
GIT_ORG=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

The first element (0) of the `BASH_REMATCH` array is the entire matched string; subsequent elements are the contents of any capture groups in the regular expression, from left to right.

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers are going to be more efficient (ie, they don't incur the overhead of spawning 4x subshells), some considerations re: OP's current `sed` solution:

- in the 1st `sed` script the `#` is used as the script delimiter
- in the 2nd `sed` script the `/` is used as the script delimiter
- the error is being generated by the 2nd `sed` script because the `/` also shows up in the data (ie, `sed` can't distinguish between a `/` used as a delimiter vs. a `/` as part of the data)
- try using `#` as the script delimiter in the 2nd `sed` command to eliminate the error message

As for the current regexes, this may be easier to address if we enable extended regex support (`-E` or `-r`), eg:

```
$ echo "$SSH_URL" | sed -nE 's#^.*:([^/]*)/.*$#\1#p'
myOrg

$ echo "$SSH_URL" | sed -nE 's#^.*/([^\.]*)\..*$#\1#p'
my-repogit
```

Eliminating the pipe/subshell with a here-string (`<<< "$var"`):

```
$ sed -nE 's#^.*:([^/]*)/.*$#\1#p' <<< "$SSH_URL"
myOrg

$ sed -nE 's#^.*/([^\.]*)\..*$#\1#p' <<< "$SSH_URL"
my-repo
```

Pulling all of this into OP's current code:

```
$ REPO=$(sed -nE 's#^.*:([^/]*)/.*$#\1#p' <<< "$SSH_URL")
$ GIT_ORG=$(sed -nE 's#^.*/([^\.]*)\..*$#\1#p' <<< "$SSH_URL")

$ typeset -p REPO GIT_ORG
declare -- REPO="myOrg"
declare -- GIT_ORG="my-repo"
```

**NOTES:**

- the `$( ... )` construct will still require a subshell to be spawned (2 total in this case)
- consider getting into the habit of using lower-cased variable names (eg, `ssh_url`, `repo` and `git_org`) to minimize the (future) chance of overwriting system variables (eg, PWD, HOME, PATH)